# How can i get path url from a local path in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a problem  in creating a download link in codeigniter.
My problem is i ahve a local path for my file name:

```
C:\wamp\www\elance\zip2\uploads/13487727859183.zip
```

Now to make the download link i need something like `http://localhost/elance/zip2/uploads/13487727859183.zip`

I am confused and not getting a solution how to do it.

Comment: have you tried `http://localhost\/elance\/zip2\/uploads\/13487727859183.zip` ?

Comment: i want to convert C:\wamp\www\elance\zip2\uploads/13487727859183.zip
to http://localhost/elance/zip2/uploads/13487727859183.zip

Comment: Sorry maybe I don't understand, but, wrap it in an `<a>` tag?

Comment: you want to convert the string C:\wamp\www\elance\zip2\uploads/13487727859183.zip to http//localhost/elance/zip2/uploads/13487727859183.zip. correct.?

Comment: If I understand the question, wouldn't just be base_url()elance/zip2/uploads/1234567890?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert `C:\wamp\www\elance\zip2\uploads/13487727859183.zip` to `http://localhost/elance/zip2/uploads/13487727859183.zip` you could simply use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$str = "C:\wamp\www\elance\zip2\uploads/13487727859183.zip";
$str = str_replace("C:\wamp\www\","http://localhost/", $str);
$str = str_replace('\\', '/', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

without testing it i think this should work just fine. the function will need to be placed in a helper

```
function create_download_link($file, $base_url, $location = "C:\wamp\www\") {

    $link = "<a href='" . str_replace("\\", "/", str_replace($location, $base_url, $file)) . "'>Download File</a>";

    return $link;

}

//example call
create_download_link("C:\wamp\www\elance\zip2\uploads/13487727859183.zip", base_url(), "C:\wamp\www\");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your problem as I had the same problem today.

Below is my one line solution, here is an explanation to make sure I understood correctly.

You have a file, and a local path for that file name, likely stored in a database table or similar... correct?

eg.  C:\wamp\www\myApp\path\to\file.zip

You want your application to spit out a link so people viewing your webpage can click on said link and download the file, correct?

your app lives at:  C:\wamp\www\myApp\index.php

The dynamic solution below will work only if your file is stored in a sub-directory of your applications root directory, and it's easy because it takes advantage of CodeIgniter's predefined constants and url helpers:

```
// FCPATH -> where the index.php file lives
// $my_file  -> your file
$file_url = str_replace(FCPATH, base_url(), $my_file);
```

That's it.

Just replace the "FCPATH" portion of the file path with the "base_url()" output and you're good to go.

If your file resides in a folder that is not a sub-folder of your app folder, you will have to hard code the FCPATH and base_url() bits...

Hope that helps!
Pete